# Generating random numbers with skewed distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random

I want to generate random numbers with skewed distribution. But I have only following information about distribution from the paper :

> skewed distribution where the value is 1 with probability 0.9 and 46 with probability 0.1. the distribution  has mean (5.5)

I don't know how to generate random numbers with this information and I don't know what is the distribution function.

I'm using [jdistlib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jdistlib/) for random number generation. If anyone has experience using this library can help me with this library for skewed distribution random number generation?

Comment: If you can generate a uniform distribution $u \in [0,1]$, then you can generate the above with $u \mapsto 1_{[0,0.9]}(u)+46 \cdot 1 _{(0.9,1]}(u)$

Comment: @copper.hat if I generate in the way you suggested, all numbers are near to 46 but I think according to distribution, numbers should be more near to 1. in the paper they said that the numbers mean is 5.5.

Comment: If $u$ is distributed normally on $[0,1]$, then $E(1_{[0,0.9]}+46 \cdot 1 _{(0.9,1]}) = 0.9+0.1 \cdot 46 = 5.5$. I'm not sure why ou think all the numbers are near to $46$. Note the multiplier on 46 is $1_{[0.9,1]}$, and $E1_{[0.9,1]} = 0.1$.

Comment: @copper.hat so maybe my problem is that I didn't know skewed distribution completely. I thought that this distribution should have numbers between 1 and 46 and mostly near to 1 so that their mean would be 5.5. but sth that you said is that we only have exact 46 and 1 numbers so that their mean would be 5.5. Do I understand you completely ?

Comment: It depends on what you want, the question says that you want the value $1$ with probability $0.9$ and the value $46$ with probability $0.1$. So that is what I did...

Comment: @copper.hat thanks, but I took this sentence from a paper "skewed distribution where the value is 1 with probability 0.9 and 46 with probability 0.1." is the way you suggested, create a skewed distribution ?

Comment: I don't know, but the sentence is fairly explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What copperhat is hinting at is the following algorithm:

```
Generate u, uniformly distributed in [0, 1]
If u < 0.9 then
   return 1
else
   return 46
```

(sorry, would be a mess as a comment).

In general, if you have a continuous distribution with cummulative distribution $c(x)$, to generate the respective numbers get $u$ as above, $c^{-1}(u)$ will have the required distribution. Can do the same with discrete distributions, essentially searching where the $u$ lies in the cummulative distribution.

An *extensive* treatment of generating random numbers (including non-uniform ones) is in Knuth's "Seminumerical Algorithms" (volume 2 of "The Art of Computer Programming"). Warning, *heavy* math involved.

Comment: so maybe my problem is that I didn't know skewed distribution completely. I thought that this distribution should have numbers between 1 and 46 and mostly near to 1 so that their mean would be 5.5. but sth that you said is that we only have exact 46 and 1 numbers so that their mean would be 5.5. Do I understand you completely ?

Comment: @user1031925, 90% of the time 1, 10% of the time 46 is what I understood of your question. That nicely gives an average of 5.5, as stated.